# Windows 10 Taskbar and multiple monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I am running Windows 10 with TWO monitors. When right-clicking the TaskBar on the MAIN Monitor, the TaskBar context menu has a "Toolbars" menu item:

[image]

But when right-clicking the TaskBar on the SECONDARY Monitor, the TaskBar context menu has NO "Toolbars" menu item:

[image]

But I need to place a specific toolbar on the secondary TaskBar!

How can I do that?

Comment: You need Windows 11 to show the task bar on multiple monitors.

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't support this. You'll need a tool such as https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/features/multi_monitor_taskbar/ for this

Comment: @John Actually, I DO HAVE the task bar on multiple monitors in Windows 10. How do you think I made the screenshots?

Comment: @1NN I have tried Actual Window Manager. It is a fantastic tool. Unfortunately, it eats too many resources.